# automatically load as fadein popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

I would like the popup to automatically set on and not have to click to make the event. Can you help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){     
   $('#open').click(function(){

     // enter code here
    $('.popup-overlay').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.popup-overlay').height($(window).height());
    return false;
});



$('#close').click(function(){
    $('#popup').fadeOut('slow');
    $('.popup-overlay').fadeOut('slow');
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="content">
   <div id="column-right"><a href="#" id="open">click aqui</a></div>

 </div>

 <div id="popup" style="display: none;">
  <div class="content-popup">
    <div class="close"><a href="#" id="close"><img src="images/close.png"/></a></div>
    <div> enter code here
        <h2>Contenido POPUP</h2>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Means whenever the page is loaded the pop up automatically opens without any client side event.

Comment: Offtopic: Nice identicon

Comment: You want it to popup on load? I don't understand. This question is mostly code.

Comment: that's right, I want the popup is automatically loaded. thanks for answering

Answer (score 2):

Just take the code out of the `click()` event:

And remove the div with .popup-overlay class. It's useless

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#popup').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#popup').height($(window).height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to fade the **#popup** also.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $('#popup').fadeIn('slow');
   $('.popup-overlay').fadeIn('slow');
   $('.popup-overlay').height($(window).height());
});
```

Comment: there is no class .popup-overlay, so I supouse that #popup should have that class

Comment: not work : [link]https://lahoradelascompras.com/sitio/SORTEO/formulario/index4.php

Comment: <div class="popup-overlay"></div>

Comment: don't you mean **.content-popup** by **.popup-overlay** , just cross check it.